# Is it possible to get design-time code completion for dynamic types?

Tags: c#, orm, code-generation, reflection.emit, dynamic-typing

I'm looking into generating types dynamically, ie. `TypeBuilder`, `Reflection.Emit`..
Is it ever possible to get design-time code completion for such created types? i.e typename recognition, list of properties after typing "`obj1.`" and such.

Full Context: Trying to generate entities and data access objects corresponding to database tables in runtime. Code generation is an option, but I wanted to see if I could do without it. Have some experience in reflection, but none in type building the reflection.emit way.

Comment: If your types are emitted at run-time, how could you possibly hope to get code-completion on them at design-time?  Or are you suggesting run-time code generation, in such a way that the generated assemblies continue to exist once the application is terminated?

Comment: That's what I also think. But I wanted to know if there is some way. A new assembly is defined when creating a new type with TypeBuilder, and if this assembly could somehow be "hooked" into visual studio code-completion like other assemblies in the project, it would be possible.

Comment: No, I'm trying to avoid code generation actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not likely without some serious designer mojo.  Emitted code isn't actually generated until runtime, which means it's not actually available at design time.  You *could* use T4 templates to generate your types that way, as the designer will evaluate the templates to build the required types, which of course are immediately available at design time.